# draw diamond shape and add in CCSprite

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to draw diamond shape in my application....

how to draw this diamond shape using CCSprite and how to detect collision between this two CCSprite..

Thanks...in advance

Comment: you can do that in Quarts 2D are you interested in that? or you just want it in CCSpirit?

Comment: Tell me how can i use Quarts 2D in this Question????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply provide an image of the diamond and initialize the CCSprite with `[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"diamond.png"]`. For collision detection you can use the physics engine Box2D, which is included in the Cocos2D SDK. You have to specify the shape of the diamond in a [Box2D fixture](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082972).

Comment: I tried with image but always image is rectangle and diamond is in the image then when i detect collision then whole image is detected mins square is detected....i want only diamond detect...

Comment: The background of the image must be transparent. As I said you have to specify the shape with Box2D (as a polygon) in order to make collision work properly. I do the same with circles.

Comment: Can you give me some code of collision detection using Box2D with CCSprite??

Comment: http://www.box2d.org/documentation.html
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/

Start reading. I don't mind when people ask questions, but when people ask for code without trying to investigate the problem themselves its aggravates me greatly.

Comment: a good starting point is the cocos2d+box2d project template for xcode

Answer (score 0):

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_Graphics_Drawing_Tutorial_using_Quartz_2D

see the section where: The following code draws a diamond shape.